# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'classFactory'

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, osx, cython

I'm trying to compile a cython plugin for QGIS. 
The plugin is working on windows (32/64) machines but was never used on Mac before.

I compiled the cython for python as described [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html) but there are still issues and code now returns above error.

File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 306, in startPlugin
                plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
            AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'classFactory'

Comment: I decided to rearrange the folder structure (originally module for windows qgis). 
The code included if statements referring to operating system and appropriate folders. I deleted windows folders and all mac .so compiled files placed to main folder. Adjusted code to address change.

Answer (score 2):

I rearranged the folder structure, bringing all modules from sub folders to main folder and adjusted code accordingly. - Current problem solved.